# What is the book about Von Neumann machines fighting each other?

Tags: story-identification

The book started with a young guy testing out a Von Neumann machine that he had designed. He was watching a planet from his space ship and the machine went crazy and started replicating until it covered the planet.

He was then enlisted by a mysterious government agent who wanted to use his machine to distract a rogue AI. The agent had a spaceship made of Von Neumann machines that could absorb additional mass and reconfigure itself, even creating a copy of itself at one point to distract an AI.

Comment: semi-duplicate of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/35109/what-is-the-name-of-this-trilogy-about-uploaded-people-in-space (about the series as a whole)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This sounds like [Recursion](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?182730) by [Tony Ballantyne](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/ea.cgi?18304). A summary from [fantasticfiction.co.uk](http://www.fantasticfiction.co.uk/b/tony-ballantyne/recursion.htm):

> It is the twenty-third century. Herb, a young entrepreneur, returns to the isolated planet on which he has illegally been trying to build a city-and finds it destroyed by a swarming nightmare of self-replicating machinery. Worse, the all-seeing Environment Agency has been watching him the entire time. His punishment? A nearly hopeless battle in the farthest reaches of the universe against enemy machines twice as fast, and twice as deadly, as his own-in the company of a disarmingly confident AI who may not be exactly what he claims.
>
> Little does Herb know that this war of machines was set in motion nearly two hundred years ago-by mankind itself. For it was then that a not-quite-chance encounter brought a confused young girl and a nearly omnipotent AI together in one fateful moment that may have changed the course of humanity forever.